# custom boost prefix/namspace - how to build with

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I need to use custom build of boost lib, which uses own library naming prefix as well as namespace in the code.

I need to link with it in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /path/to/custom/boost/include)
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR /path/to/custom/boost/lib)
set(BOOST_NAMESPACE my_boost_161)
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS OFF)

set (Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
find_package (Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS my_unit_test_framework)
include_directories (${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

the libraries have a names like :

> libmy_boost_161_unit_test_framework.so

and really exist in lib folder

there is a errors like:

> CMake Error at
>   /home/user1/.localcmake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2132
>   (message):   Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
>
> Boost version: 1.61.0
>
> Boost include path:
>   /path/to/custom/boost/include
>
> Could not find the following Boost libraries:
>
> ```
>       boost_unit_test_framework
> ```
>
> No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR
>   to the   directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the
>   location of

How can I specify to look for libs with names like (`my_` addition to standard names):
similar to `Boost_LIB_VERSION`      which gives an ability to add the version to lib name

> my_boost_161_unit_test_framework

Comment: Message `Could not find the following Boost libraries:` contains *logical* name of the library. For find, which **filename** is searching, pass `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` option to `cmake`.

Comment: thank you very much for the flag, it shows me detailed info and I could find required flags and solve my problem. Boost_LIB_PREFIX and Boost_NAMESPACE are helpful for my issue

Comment: @amigo421 If your issue was solved, please consider writing an answer post so others know how you solved it. And mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This addition to the CMake script fixes the problem:

```
...
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS OFF)

set(Boost_LIB_PREFIX my_boost_161)
set(Boost_NAMESPACE my_boost_161)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
...
```